# What is wrong with whitespaces in ANTLR?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing, antlr, antlr3

I have really simple XML (HTML) parsing ANTLR grammar:

```
wiki: ggg+;

ggg: tag | text;

tag: '<' tx=TEXT { System.out.println($tx.getText()); } '>';

text: tx=TEXT { System.out.println($tx.getText()); };

CHAR: ~('<'|'>');
TEXT: CHAR+;
```

With such input: `"<ggg> fff"` it works fine.

But when I start to deal with whitespaces it fails. For example:

- `" <ggg> fff "` - fails at beggining
- `"<ggg> <hhh> "` - fails after `<ggg>`
- `"<ggg> fff "` - works fine
- `"<ggg> "` - fails at end

I don't know what is wrong. Maybe there is some special grammar option to handle this. ANTLRWorks gives me `NoViableAltException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR's lexer rules match as much as possible. Only when 2 (or more) rule(s) match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will "win". Because of that, a single character other than `'<'` and `'>'` is tokenized as a `CHAR` token, and not as `TEXT` token, regardless of what the parser "needs" (the lexer operates independently from the parser, remember that!). Only two or more characters other than `'<'` and `'>'` are being tokenized as a (single) `TEXT` token.

So, therefor the input `" <ggg> fff "` creates the following 5 tokens:

```
type    | text
--------+-----------
CHAR    |   ' '
'<'     |   '<'
TEXT    |   'ggg'
'>'     |   '>'
TEXT    |   ' fff '
```

And since the token `CHAR` is not accounted for in your parser rule(s), the parse fails.

Simply remove `CHAR` and do:

```
TEXT : ~('<'|'>')+;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have no token to deal with the space. A space for a lexer is no different from any other character it may encounter.

If whitespace is unimportant you can simply use:

```
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

If whitespace is important to you:

```
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+
CHAR: ~('<'|'>');
TEXT: (CHAR|WHITESPACE)+;
```

Comment: Whitespaces are important to me.

You wrote that a space for a lexer is no different from any other character.
But in my example CHAR token should match any whitespace character. So it should works but it does not. Conclusion: whitespace for a lexer is different from others characters!

Comment: And that you gived is wrong because there are multiple alternatives (WHITESPACE and CHAR).

Comment: @pablo, you are right in the fact that your lexer rule `CHAR` accounts for space-chars, but your conclusion is wrong. I'll explain shortly in an answer.